# Enumerate List Changing Font Size

Tags: fonts, enumerate

I want to make a "double" list using enumerate such that the outside is bold and italic and the inside is normal font. I tried using this code that I came up with:

```
\large\textbf{\textit{
\begin{enumerate}

\item Proofs
\normalfont{\normalsize{
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Proof by Contradiction
    \item Mathematical Induction
    \item Pigeonhole Principle
    \item Parity Argument
\end{enumerate}}}

\item Divisibility
\end{enumerate}}}
```

It works with the first item, but it fell apart for the second item. This is what I have when it is compiled on Overleaf:

[image]

How can I fix it so that the "Divisibility" is also bold and italic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple with `enumitem`and its `before` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[before=\large\itshape\bfseries]
\item Proofs
\begin{enumerate}[before=\normalfont\normalsize]
    \item Proof by Contradiction
    \item Mathematical Induction
    \item Pigeonhole Principle
    \item Parity Argument
\end{enumerate}
\item Divisibility
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you. Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect that `\normalfont` is not a command with an argument, but a simple directive, which means: from this point on, use normal font, so that it's not limited to the nested enumerate (contrary to the  before` key`).

Comment: Ohhh I see thanks

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lbi}[1]{{\large\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\lbi{\arabic*.}}]
\item
\lbi{Proofs}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Proof by Contradiction
    \item Mathematical Induction
    \item Pigeonhole Principle
    \item Parity Argument
\end{enumerate}
\item
\lbi{Divisibility}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]